# Tailwind CSS, React JS - Transition and Transform causing overlapping on NavBar

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

I am new to Tailwind Styling and CSS styling in general.
I am using React and have created a header(Navbar) for my page to be **fixed**. It consists of two components and the code for them is as shown below:

```
import React from "react";
import { IoMdHelpCircleOutline } from "react-icons/io";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white  w-full shadow-md ">
      <div className="z-40 w-full">
        <div className=" bg-white  border-b border-mgray">
          <nav className=" w-full h-auto ">
            <ul className="text-nav_inactive flex px-3 pt-3 pb-1.5 mx-auto">
              <li className="rounded-md transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-mid_blue hover:text-white hover:shadow-lg">
                <Link to="/wb" className="px-3 pb-1">
                  Google Resources
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="rounded-md transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-mid_blue hover:text-white hover:shadow-lg">
                <Link to="/tst" onClick="" className="px-3 pb-1">
                  Tst
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="rounded-md transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-mid_blue hover:text-white hover:shadow-lg">
                <Link to="/option" onClick="" className="px-3 pb-1">
                  Option
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Head() {
  return (
    <div className="fixed w-screen bg-gradient-to-b from-l2_blue to-dark_blue">
      <div id="" className="px-8 py-4">
        <Link
          to="/"
          alt="BL Link"
          className="text-2xl text-white"
        >
          Homepage
        </Link>
        <span className="text-sm p-1 px-2 inline-flex text-gray transition duration-500 ease-in-out bg-blue-600 transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110">
          <a
            href="https://www.google.com"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            <IoMdHelpCircleOutline />
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
      <NavBar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Head;
```

***Note:*** *The div returned from Head() div is fixed.*

Next, On the page is another component. When scrolling the page then certain icons,etc are rendered over the navbar. The code for it is below:

```
function NextPart() {
  let match = useRouteMatch();
  console.log(match);
  return (
    <div className="px-3 pt-32 ">
      <div id="outer_div" className="bg-barc-white p-4 rounded shadow-lg">
        <div id="first_row" className="inline-flex pb- w-full">
          <div id="title_testUri" className="w-full inline-flex">
            <h2 className="text-3xl px-4 text-barc-dark_blue self-center">
              Sub
            </h2>
            <span className="text-xs text-barc-bgray self-center">
              A smaller part
              <a
                href="https://www.yahoo.com"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noreferrer"
                className="text-xs text-barc-nav_inactive inline-flex "
              >
                <span className="m-auto text-sm px-0.5 text-barc-mid_blue transition duration-500 ease-in-out bg-blue-600 transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110">
                  <IoMdHelpCircleOutline />
                </span>
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The images below will describe the issue:

1. This is the normal fixed view of the page without scrolling.
   [image]

---

2. When scrolled, certain button overlap on the navbar as shown in the screenshot below:
   [image]

I tried removing the Transition and Transform on the Icons and found that the issue is solved. I want to implement these transforms and transition but without overlapping. Please help me out.

Also, if any additional details are required regarding the question please feel free to comment and I will edit the post to include the relevant details.

Thank You! :)

Comment: You can probably add the class `z-10` to your fixed head element and take care of it.

Comment: @JHeth Thank You, it solved my issue.

Comment: Happy to help, you can mark your answer as correct to resolve this post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @JHeth in the comment above, adding z-index (specifically z-10) to the Head() first(fixed) div solved my issue.

Thank you @JHeth :)